# Including Div with IDs inside of the php echo function

Tags: php, html, echo

OK heres the code.

```
$c_time = mktime();
$open = strtotime('Today 5pm');
$close = strtotime('Today 7pm');

if ($c_time > $open && $c_time < $close) {
echo ' THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO ADD DIVs';
}
     else {
         echo 'DISPLAY THIS CODE.';
}

?>
```

That's the working piece of code I have which basically states that if the time is between 5 and 7pm display the first set of code, if not display what is in the Else tags.... that bits easy and works.

however, i want to include the following piece of php/html inside the echo tags I've read somewhere that you need to replace ' with \' but haven't been able to implement it.

```
<div id="animated-head-link"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="Return to <?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>' Homepage." rel="home">
        <div id="sky">
            <div id="logo">         </div><!-- END LOGO -->
            <div id="clouds">       </div><!-- END CLOUDS -->
            <div id="mountains">    </div><!-- END MOUNTAINS -->
        </div><!-- END SKY -->
</a> </div><!-- END ANIMATED-HEAD-LINK -->
```

This piece of code also works fine on it's own but doesn't work when echoed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest and most readble way would be to use the alternate syntax:

```
<?php

$c_time = mktime();
$open = strtotime('Today 5pm');
$close = strtotime('Today 7pm');
?>

<?php if ($c_time > $open && $c_time < $close): ?> 

  <div id="animated-head-link">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="Return to  <?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>' Homepage." rel="home">

        <div id="sky">

            <div id="logo">         </div><!-- END LOGO -->

            <div id="clouds">       </div><!-- END CLOUDS -->

            <div id="mountains">    </div><!-- END MOUNTAINS -->

        </div><!-- END SKY -->

    </a> 
  </div><!-- END ANIMATED-HEAD-LINK -->

<?php else: ?>
  DISPLAY THIS CODE.
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH, I don't have a high enough rep on here to vote for you but thank you very much. I'm going to use this site more as I never get a response on the wordpress forums. I will tick it in 6 minutes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are echoing the html, and inside the html there are PHP tags. Since you are echoing the code from php you need to remove the inner php tags and just use the dot to concatenate the strings:

```
echo '<div id="animated-head-link"><a href="'
. esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) 
. '" title="Return to '
. esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) )
. ' Homepage." rel="home">

    <div id="sky">

        <div id="logo">         </div><!-- END LOGO -->

        <div id="clouds">       </div><!-- END CLOUDS -->

        <div id="mountains">    </div><!-- END MOUNTAINS -->

    </div><!-- END SKY -->

</a> </div><!-- END ANIMATED-HEAD-LINK -->';
```

Comment: I wanted to give you another option, but I agree that actually prodigitalson's answer is better. Both will work but his/hers is more readable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer it is actually closer to what I had written originally but I kept getting parse errors so thought I would post the question. This is correct, but you are also correct in sayinf that prodgitalson's answer is just so simple. (plus it preserves the wordpress head link call in it's original state.

Answer (score 0):

don't Worry you cant use simple quotes for skip the restriction of double quotes 
PD: change the function `mktime()` to `time()`
the code look will this

```
enter code here
<?php 
$c_time = time();
$open = strtotime('Today 5pm');
$close = strtotime('Today 7pm');
if ($c_time > $open && $c_time < $close) {
echo '
<div id="animated-head-link"><a href="'.esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ).'" title="Return to '.esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ).' Homepage." rel="home">

    <div id="sky">

        <div id="logo">         </div><!-- END LOGO -->

        <div id="clouds">       </div><!-- END CLOUDS -->

        <div id="mountains">    </div><!-- END MOUNTAINS -->

    </div><!-- END SKY -->
</a> </div> <!-- END ANIMATED-HEAD-LINK -->
';}else {
echo 'DISPLAY THIS CODE.';
}?>
```